# context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] is string empty

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-7, iis-7.5

I am running web app on windows7 enterprise iis7.5.
My webapp uses Windows Authentication and ASP.NET v4.0 applicationpool with `identity=applicationpoolIdentity`.

I want to get the logon user name with `context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]`, but it's string is empty. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you use punctuation, I've fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `context.User.Identity.Name` instead.

HTH.

Comment: Brian, i try what you said but i get that context.User is null.so exception was throw. thanks any way.

Comment: With windows authentication, this would work on the same network like an intranet application, but an internet application, unless all on the same domain, would not be able to use windows auth, and hence it would be null.

Comment: i stay with integrated application pool mode, but move the interception where i get the logon user to PostAuthenticationRequest (before it was in the AuthenticationRequest event handler), and now it's work